# When does `[::]` or `0.0.0.0` mean this network and when this host?

Tags: networking, route, ip-address, port

Tanenbaum's Computer Networks says

> The IP address 0.0.0.0, the lowest address, is **used by hosts when they
>   are being booted**. It means **‘‘this network’’ or ‘‘this host.’’**

`[::]`   is IPv6 version of IPv4's `0.0.0.0`.

### Questions:

1) When does `[::]`  or `0.0.0.0` mean this network and when this host?

2) When it means this host, does it mean all the network interfaces on this host, or just one specified network interface on this host?

3) Why does `[::]`   allow me to access the mysql server from other hosts in the same LAN?   Does it mean this network or this host here? Why is  `[::]` used by mysql server, although the host is not in the case "when they are being booted"?

```
   $ sudo netstat -ap | grep mysql
   tcp6       0      0 [::]:mysql              [::]:*                  LISTEN      23683/mysqld        
   tcp6       0      0 [::]:33060              [::]:*                  LISTEN      23683/mysqld        
   unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1169294  23683/mysqld         /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
   unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1169513  23683/mysqld         /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
   unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    1169211  23683/mysqld
```

Thanks.

Comment: From my understanding `[::]` and `0.0.0.0` is for local host only unless there is static route or default route set on the network!

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/507564/what-do-0-0-0-0-mysql-and-mean-in-netstat-output You completely ignored the answer you've got. And how it's not the case? Doesn't the MySQL server run exactly the same machine with netstat?

Comment: @StephenKitt Your link doesn't answer the "this network" part. I am also still not sure about "0.0.0.0 is used only as a source address", so I left a comment there.

Comment: 0.0.0.0 means a local socket by convention, at least in unixes. It roots in that the `sockaddr.s_addr` part of the `sockaddr_in` struts remain empty (0) in their case. It is a different, deeper thing than `127.0.0.1`, what is simply the IP of the `lo` loopback network interface.

Answer (score 2):

In the `netstat` output you gave, the "0.0.0.0" and "[::]" don't mean "this host", they mean that the services in question are listening on "all interfaces on this host". Thus, those ports are open for any host to connect to, including the local host.

Comment: Thanks. "services in question are listening on all interfaces on this host", are such service also listening on those IP addresses which are not bound to any (virtual or physical) network interface? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/508007/when-does-an-ip-address-not-need-to-be-assigned-to-a-network-interface

Comment: In the case of the loopback address and network in the question you referred to, yes. 127.0.0.1 is also referred to as "localhost" or "loopback", meaning "this IP references the host itself". But be careful of extrapolating behavior of any 127.*.*.* address to any other address - the loopback network (127/8) has always behaved very differently.

Comment: Thanks. May I ask  what Stephen meant by "0.0.0.0 isn’t valid as a destination address, only as a source address"? When mysql server listens at 0.0.0.0,  Is it not the destination of a request sent from a mysql client?  How  can it be used as a source? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/419881/674

Comment: When a service is listening on "0.0.0.0", it is actually listening on "all IPv4 addresses on this host". So no, 0.0.0.0 is not a valid destination address for incoming requests, instead valid destinations are "all extant IPv4 addresses on this machine".

Comment: If there is a :::8080, but do not have 0.0.0.0:8080, can we use IPv4 to access the :::8080?

Comment: Most of the time, yes. Modern Linux systems will only show ":::8080" when a service is listening on both IPv4 and IPv6 port 8080, and will automatically "forward" the IPv4 connection to the listening IPv6 port (not entirely a technically accurate description, but it gets the meaning across).

Answer (score 2):

Be careful to note the official IP definition in RFC 1122 is `this host on this network`.  This **the** official definition.  However OS specific uses still exist.

Linux's internal use of `[::]` and `0.0.0.0` are better thought of as "Null" from other areas of computing.  Depending on context "null" can mean "nothing", "don't know", "don't care" or occasionally "error".  Its meaning is really context sensitive.

IP addresses can be used to represent a network or host.  Eg **192.168.1.1** is a host on **192.168.1.0**/24.  Which it represents entirely depends on what the software was expecting to receive.

> When it means this host, does it mean all the network interfaces on this host, or just one specified network interface on this host?

When referring to bound (listening) sockets, it means "don't care" which IP.  But that is limited to only the IPs for the current host, so in practice means connections will be accepted on any interface addressed to any IP from the current host.

Comment: If there is a `:::8080`, but do not have `0.0.0.0:8080`, can we use IPv4 to access the `:::8080`?

Comment: By default on most unix-like systems applications listening on :: can also accept IPv4 connections, but this can be overridden by socket options. Windows is the opposite disabled by default but can be enabled by socket options.